# Configure (connect to) TP-Link EAP120

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I'm shy for this question, but really I'm stuck with the TP-Link AEP120 access point.
Are 3 new devices. Following the official docs (http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-811.html) I turn ON the device, I see the right SSID, connect to without password, but I don't get any IP or DNS configuration, so I can't open tplinkeap.net
I also tried the wired method but I don't see the new router in the LAN (we have DHCP).

Finally I found this [video](https://youtu.be/E3wl5PyGnHM) and followed the instructions with 'EAP Controller' software, but yet I don't see the AP.

I guess this must be something very simple to get, but really I'm stuck!
Thanks in advance

(We have 3 new devices, so, I tried with all of them for be sure is not some fault in one of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I created a independent LAN with a small router with only the laptop and the EAP120. In the DHCP configuration found the AP's IP, connect through the browser and can configure it. Also, with this setting, EAP Controller software connect without problem. I don't know if a third device in the original 'big' LAN made some noise.

I will mark the question like 'answered' but I will like if anybody comment with more information.

Thanks anyway.

UPDATE: Answer from TP-LINK support

> For the EAP120, only the first firmware version supports the cluster
> mode. Please check the firmware version on the TP-LINK official
> website:
> http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Auranet-EAP120.html#Firmware
>
> The new firmware version doesn't support the cluster mode any more. By the
> way, the cluster mode cannot use the controller.
> For the cluster mode, please refer to this link: http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-772.html
>
> If the firmware version is not the 20141107, it doesn't support cluster
> mode.

For the records, I installed EAP Controller 2.2.3 and upgraded the firmware to EAP120(UN)_V1_160107, now everything is working ok.

Thanks to the TP-Link support.